# Python skip the lines which do not have any of starting line in the output

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I am trying to write a code after getting help from google and So to parse a command output but still getting some problem, as the output what i am expecting continuous there line starting with `dn` , `instance` and `tag` but somehow the very first output only contains `dn` and `tag` So,  i want those line which do not have all these three starting strings then just skip those,  as i am learning so not getting the idea to do that.

### Below is my code:

```
import subprocess as sp

p = sp.Popen(somecmd, shell=True, stdout=sp.PIPE)
stout = p.stdout.read().decode('utf8')
output = stout.splitlines()
startline = ["instance:", "tag"]
for line in output:
    print(line)
```

### Script output:

```
dn: ou=People,ou=pti,o=pt
tag: pti00631

dn: cn=pti00857,ou=People,ou=pti,o=pt
instance: Jassu Lal
tag: pti00857

dn: cn=pti00861,ou=People,ou=pti,o=pt
instance: Gatti Lal
tag: pti00861
```

### Desired output:

```
dn: cn=pti00857,ou=People,ou=pti,o=pt
instance: Jassu Lal
tag: pti00857

dn: cn=pti00861,ou=People,ou=pti,o=pt
instance: Gatti Lal
tag: pti00861
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your output *always* the same, your loop can look like this:

```py
lines_to_skip = 3
skip_lines = False
skipped_lines = 0

for line in output():

    if "dn: " in line and not "dn: cn" in line:
        skip_lines = True

    if skip_lines:
        if skipped_lines < lines_to_skip:
            skipped_lines += 1
            continue

        if skipped_lines == lines_to_skip:
            skip_lines = False
            skipped_lines = 0

    print(line)
```

It will check if there is a `dn` without the `cn`, counts to 3 (or rather `lines_to_skip`) and starts outputting when it's reached the lines to skip.

It's a pretty hacky solution but the best one I could come up with for the given context

Answer (score 1):

The below code is flexible. You only need to add the tags in the `necessary_tags`  dictionary without which you do not want to print. It can be more than 3 as well. It also accounts for situations when you receive a particular tag more than once.

```
import subprocess as sp

p = sp.Popen(somecmd, shell=True, stdout=sp.PIPE)
stout = p.stdout.read().decode('utf8')
output = stout.splitlines()

output.append("")
necessary_tags = {'dn':0, 'instance':0, 'tag':0}
temp_output = []

for line in (output):
  tag = line.split(':')[0].strip()

  if necessary_tags.get(tag, -1) != -1:
    necessary_tags[tag] += 1
    temp_output.append(line)
    
  elif line == "":
    if all(necessary_tags.values()):
      for out in temp_output:
        print(out)
    temp_output = []
    necessary_tags.update({}.fromkeys(necessary_tags,0))
    print()
```